# Could not run google map project on android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-logcat

I have been trying to implement a Google map on my project, as I am new so far I was following this: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/
but the problem happening is my project isn't running even after following this. 
While its opening apps it's crashing on opening. Could you give some suggestion what may the cause??

Heres the logcat error -

```
08-30 15:54:02.440: D/AndroidRuntime(912): Shutting down VM
08-30 15:54:02.440: W/dalvikvm(912): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a44ba8)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912): Process: info.androidhive.googlemapsv2, PID: 912
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2-1, /system/lib]]
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/info.androidhive.googlemapsv2-1, /system/lib]]
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
08-30 15:54:02.540: E/AndroidRuntime(912):  ... 11 more
08-30 15:54:06.140: I/Process(912): Sending signal. PID: 912 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Are you trying to launch a project on an Android Emulator or real device? Google Play Services work on a real device only but not on Emulator.

Comment: oh i was trying on emulator :/ right now i dont have any device , anyway to make this work?

Comment: Theoretically it's possible but will require some strengths to make it working cause Emulator is not designed to work with Google services. You need to find and install Google Play Services .apk files on Emulator through ADB, http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/01/09/google-play-services-4-1-begins-rollout-with-turn-based-multiplayer-new-google-drive-api-preview-and-more/

Comment: Here is another URL with Android SDK Extras, see Google Play Services, http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-sdk-extras-by-google-inc.html , to install .apk using ADB, https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527

Comment: i tried these steps , installing those 2 apk's on my emulator , but unfortunately even though they are installed this googlemap program doesn't work , and those two installed apps doesn't run on emulator they also crashed :(

Comment: You need to find the latest version of those apk's though it doesn't guarantee. I had to reinstall a Google Play Service .apk several times but I advise to find a real Android device.

Comment: Also I used HAXM, Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager to encrease the speed of Emulator, https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager .